# Deducing that $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]/(y^2,xy)$ is not reduced.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I want to get the result why $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]/(y^2,xy)$ is not reduced.  Some trials that I imagine or consider are:

- Naively, the negation of reduced scheme means there exists an open set $U$ in $X$, such that $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ has nilpotent element.
- Or, by using the equivalence relation of the definition of non-reduced : there exists an open affine scheme  $U_i \simeq \operatorname{Spec}R_i$ such that  $\mathcal{O}_{X} (U_i)$ is not reduced.
- Observing that the given ring, $k[x,y]/(y^2,xy)$, is isomorphic to another ring.( For example, (if $k$ is a field) , then since $k[x]/(x^2)$ is isomorphic to $k$, whence $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]/(x^2) \simeq \left\{pt\right\} $ has not reduced . )
- Try to understnd the given ring strcture, $k[x,y]/(y^2,xy)$ : According to the [Ravi Vakil's lecture note](https://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/0708-216/216class0910.pdf), the lecturer describes $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]/(y^2,xy)$. (The lecturer seems to call the ball in the middle of the line a "fuzz")

[image]

But all strategies are not easy for me. Especially, if I understand the following picture $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]/(y^2,xy)$  , it would be helpful to some extent. But I cannot explain why such scheme is described like FIGURE1.

Comment: For intuition behind the figure: are you familiar with the double point interpretation or $\text{Spec} \left(k[x]/(x^2)\right)$ ?

Comment: I know $k[x]/(x^2)$ is a field, (in fact, it is an algebraic extension). Or, someone calls the given field $k[x]/(x^2)$ a "dual of ring", (frankly, I can't understand well why they call it the dual of ring)  That is all I can reply on the comment.

Comment: It is not a field since $(x^2)$ is not maximal ($(x)$ properly contains it). Additionally, $x^2 = 0$, so it is not even an integral domain domain.

Answer (score 2):

Your first bullet point contains the answer. You have $\mathcal{O}_X(X)=k[x,y]/(xy, y^2)$. In this ring, $y^2=0$.

Answer (score 1):

In your global sections, you have a non-zero element $\bar{y}$ such that $\bar{y}^2 \equiv 0$.