# Geometrical meaning of double points(or fat points)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I asked the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4442828/deducing-that-operatornamespec-kx-y-y2-xy-is-not-reduced?noredirect=1#comment9304335_4442828) in the past. The focus on my question is the title itself, but I was little curious about the concept of the "double points" (or "fat points") at the sight of [Ravi Valki's lecture note](https://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/0708-216/216class0910.pdf). To begin with, I read up on the concept of dual ring, because , like the comment of the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4442828/deducing-that-operatornamespec-kx-y-y2-xy-is-not-reduced?noredirect=1#comment9304335_4442828), I was not ready to understand the concept of double points back then. And instead of the Valki's note, I referred the [Gathman's lecture note](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/%7Egathmann/class/alggeom-2021/alggeom-2021-c12.pdf) in page 96.  Here, I transcribe the Gattman's explanation about the double points:

> *Geometrically, one can think of $\operatorname{Spec}R$ as “a point
> that extends infinitesimally in one direction”: As on the affine line
> $\mathbb{A}_{k}^{1}$, there are polynomial functions in one variable on
> $\operatorname{Spec}R$, but the space is such an infinitesimally small
> neighborhood of the origin that we can only see the linearization of
> the functions on it, and that it does not contain any actual points
> except $0$.*

If $R={k[x]}/{(x^2)}$ , then $\operatorname{Spec}R$ is just one point,$(x)$, and clearly the point would not mean a geometrical point like a point $P$ on the line or segment, because indeed the point is a principal ideal. Also, every (principle) ideal contains $(0)$,  Hence, in my conclusion after I read the Gathman's note :

- it is plausible $(x) \in  \operatorname{Spec}R$ is fatter than the geometrical point.
- the double point is located in the middle of affine line $\mathbb{A}_{k}^{1}$ , i.e it bloats throughout near the origin point.

However, I have yet to understand the geometrical meaning described on the Gathman's lecture, espeically, "**infinitesimally**" in one direction. Obviously, it is impossible that the double point eat out all affine line. However, I do not surely catch why the double points occupies only very small area of affine line.

Here is my attempt (why the point extends **infinitesimally**) :

the double point $(x)$ is a set and the set is written as $(x)=\left\{\bar{r}x : \bar{r} \in R\right\}$. (where $\bar{r}$ is a representation of $R$). when considering this set, the element of  $(x)$ is likely to be dotted sporadically on  $\mathbb{A}_{k}^{1}$.-- this is my thought I believe. But, it would be impossible, because $R$ is not reduced ring , that means $R=k[x]/(x^2)$ has a nilpotent element. When considering [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4442828/deducing-that-operatornamespec-kx-y-y2-xy-is-not-reduced?noredirect=1#comment9304335_4442828), whenever I pick an (nonzero) element $\bar{r} \in R ~,~ \bar{r}^{2}=\bar{0}$. Thus, it is impossible that the point is dotted affine line here and there. For example, when considering $\bar{y}= \bar{r}^{31}x \in (x)$, but $\bar{r}^{31}x= (\bar{r}^2)^{15}\cdot \bar{r} x=\bar{0}\cdot \bar{r} x = \bar{0}$. ( I just expect the point $\bar{y}$ would be located far away from the origin point, $\bar{0}$, but my expectation clearly fails)  Anyway, the double point cannot expand around the origin point, $\bar{0}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are taking the ball a little too literally. The word infinitesimal should be interpreted in the sense of calculus. If I have a function $f = 3+x+x^2$ at a point $x=0$, then $f(0) = 3$ is the basic information of the value of the function at the point where as $f'(0) = 1$ and $f''(0) = 2$ are what we think of as infinitesimal information. The idea is that if you reduce a function of $k[x]$ modulo a reduced ideal $I$, you lose all the infinitesimal information but if you reduce it modulo a non-reduced ideal $I$, you get to retain some of the infinitesimal information. Gathmann and Vakil just indicate this using a little ball around the point. A much more detailed explanation below:

For a ring $R$ and an ideal $I$, we have the natural map $ R \to R/I$ taking an element $f \mapsto \overline f$, it's *reduction* in the quotient. The term reduction itself implies that we are forgetting or throwing away some information. The intuition for fat points now is that when we reduce $f$, it remembers more than just it's value at the underlying scheme

The following examples just expand on this idea:

- If $R = \mathbb Z$ and $I = (5)$, then which object do you think retains more information? The integer $7428$ or it's reduction $\overline 3$? Obviously the former, since an element of $\mathbb Z$ contains way more information than an element of $\mathbb Z/ 5 \mathbb Z$. **So under the reduction map to $\mathbb Z/ 5 \mathbb Z$, the number $7428$ loses all information except it's remainder modulo $5$.**
- If $R = \mathbb Z$ and $I = (25)$, then which object do you think retains more information? The integer $7428$ or it's reduction $\overline 8$? Obviously the former, since an element of $\mathbb Z$ contains way more information than an element of $\mathbb Z/ 25 \mathbb Z$. This is still a lot less information than the original integer $7428$ but is still more information than the reduction of $7428$ modulo $5$.
- Similarly, if $R = k[x]$ and $I = (x)$, which object do you think retains more information? The polynomial $f = x^3+3x^2-x+4$ or it's reduction ( or equivalently it's value at $x=0$) of $4$? Obviously the former since the full polynomial remembers a lot more: for instance it knows its values at all other field values in $k$, you can take it's derivatives, etc. **So under the reduction map to $k[x]/(x)$, the polynomial $f$ loses all information except it's value at $x=0$.**
- Now lets deal with $R = k[x]$ and $I = (x^2)$. Then the reductions of a polynomial $f = a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots a_1x+a_0$ has representative $a_1x+a_0$. **So under the reduction, the function $f$ is remembering BOTH it's value at $0$, i.e. $a_0$ as well as it's derivative at $0$**, i.e. $a_1$. We are still losing a lot of information but remembering more than if $I = (x)$.
- More generally if $I = (x^n)$, we remember the value of $f$ at $0$ as well as the additional coefficients $a_1, a_2,\ldots a_{n-1}$.
- So the punchline is that being a fatpoint means that under the reduction map $R \to R/I$, (where $I$ is now not a reduced ideal) the functions remember a bit more than just their value.